# Best way to implement form in Layout page in ASP.Net MVC 3 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My site has a login box in the Layout page on which every page is based. When the Login button is clicked, no matter it is successful or failure, the user will be sent to the same page where the Login button is clicked.
The login form is posted to Account.Login action method. However, how can I return the correct view at the end of this action method? I also want to show error information beside the login box ie: wrong username/password in the case of failure to login.

What's the best way to design and implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       //TODO : Log user in

       return View("ValidModelView");  
    }

    // If login model is not valid
    return View("InvalidModelView"); 
}
```

One approach might be this. However, I am not sure whether it is the best one.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a Redirect on successful login.

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```